# Why direction is from sphere center to origin of the ray in ray tracer?

Tags: glsl, webgl, raytracing

I have read the ray-tracer tutorial here

https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-sphere-intersection

and want to achieve it following this code

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MdXSD8

But I'm wondering why L in the pic presented as this?

```
vec3 oc = ro - sphere.xyz
```

[image]

I think it should be a vector from the ray origin point to sphere center?

From O to C in the pic?

```
vec3 oc = sphere.xyz - ro
```

Comment: Probably right, but the `-b` in `t = (-b - sqrt(h));` corrects that. Change to `vec3 oc = sph.xyz - ro;` and `t = (b - sqrt(h));` and the code will work too.

Comment: Note, if `b=dot(A-B,C)` then `-b = -dot(A-B,C) = dot(-(A-B),C) = dot(B-A,C)`